# Canon Pixma 145 Problem: Every print job is stopped

Tags: printing, canon

I am having problems with my printer.
It is a Canon Pixma 145 printer.
I haven't explicitly loaded any drivers since the printer was already detected but every time I try to print something, the job is stopped.
I went through some forums and got to know the following in the localhost:

```
The PPD version (5.2.11) is not compatible with Gutenprint 5.2.12.
Please run '/usr/sbin/cups-genppdupdate' as administrator.
```

The following is a screenshot that I take:
[image: Screenshot]
What should I do?

Comment: Please run `sudo /usr/sbin/cups-genppdupdate` in a terminal, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/956621/edit) your question and add the terminal output using a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your prompt reply. While I was at it, i deleted the printer and connected it again. Somehow, that worked and I am able to print documents now.

Comment: If you found a solution please add it as an answer below.